# Custom @Column JPA Annotations, how to?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-annotations

Been trying hard to search for a solution to create some Custom JPA Annotations to replace repetitive fields when declaring Entity POJOs. Any help? Here what I am trying to achieve:

```
//@Column(name = "is_enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1")
@ColumnBooleanNotNullDefaultOne
private Boolean isEnabled;
```

**or**

```
//@Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@ColumnTimestamp
private Timestamp created;
```

However, my attempts are failing...

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Column // <-- Error here (The annotation @Column is disallowed for this location.)
public @interface BooleanNotNullDefaultOne
{

}
```

Any help is definatelly aprecciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a new Class that implements UserType and use this annotation:

```
@Type(type="fully.qualified.name.of.YourUserType")
```

Also, the @Column annotation can only be used on a method or variable.  Take a look at the @Target of the Column interface definition to understand why.

Comment: It's funny how Hibernate asks you to implement 11 methods for your "UserType" and in the end, you have to @Type("giganticQualifiedClassPath"), but I will def take a look at it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: There is a way to create a short name for those, but I never bothered to figure it out.  Good luck!

Comment: Maybe import the annotation class?

Comment: I suppose you could do @Type(type=YourUserType.class.getName()), but then you're counting on the fact that the custom type would be loaded before the entity.