# How to wrap @Column annotation with my own annotation in Java or Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

I simply want to have my own annotation to clean up the annotation mass and to be able to change them easily when I want;

```
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.validation.constraints.Size
class Foo(){
    @Column(name="bar_", nullable = false, length = 32)
    @Size(min = 32, max = 32)
    String bar;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 32)
    @Size(min = 32, max = 32)
    String bas;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 32, unique=true)
    @Size(min = 32, max = 32)
    String baq;
}
```

Wish I could

```
class Foo(){
    @MyColumn(name="bar_")
    String bar;

    @MyColumn
    String bas;

    @MyColumn(unique=true)
    String baq;
}
```

`nullable = false, length = 32` are the default params.

Java or Kotlin solutions are welcome.

Comment: Not sure if you can use the solution mentioned in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346441/custom-column-jpa-annotations-how-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using 3-rd party annotations imported from `javax` the best option is to introduce a composite annotation. (Kotlin [doesn't support](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/inherited-annotations-and-other-reflections-enchancements/6209) annotation inheritance.

```kotlin
@Column(name = "bar_", nullable = false, length = 32)
@Size(min = 32, max = 32)
annotation class Anno
```

Spring boot is doing a pretty good job combining tons of config annotations all together - [check it out](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html).

There is a problem with composite annotation `Anno`, tho. You have to supply annotation parameters with constant values.

If you're sure, you need a parametrised annotation like

```kotlin
@Column(...)
@Size(min = Anno.max, max = Anno.min)
annotation class Anno(val min: Int, val max: Int)
```

have a look at [Kapt](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) or Kotlin Compiler plugins, you will need a piece of code generation.

With Kapt or Kotlin compiler plugin you will need just to override a `newField` method of your custom `ClassBuilder`:

```kotlin
  override fun newField(
      origin: JvmDeclarationOrigin,
      access: Int,
      name: String,
      desc: String,
      signature: String?,
      value: Any?
  ): FieldVisitor {
    // if field is annotated with Anno -- add two custom annotation with parameters of your choice
    // otherwise perform a standard field init
  }
```

And then register it with

```kotlin
class AnnoRegister : ComponentRegistrar {
  override fun registerProjectComponents(
      project: MockProject,
      configuration: CompilerConfiguration
  ) {
    ...
  }
```

It should be relatively easy to integrate this processing into an existing gradle or maven project, or just pass to `kotlinc`.

Comment: So the answer is there is no easy way

Answer (score 0):

For the size you could use

```
@Size(min = 32, max = 32)
@Inherited
annotation class DefaultSize()
```

However having dynamic parameters for the super, like the `name` in the `@Column` complicates things a bit. I believe you need some kind of runtime annotation modifications for that, see [Changing Annotation Parameters Runtime](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params)